# Shifting order list for playing card game

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a Windows Form C# virtual playing card game,  there are 10 players, and they all take it in turn to act. After each round, the person who acts first rotates as the dealer rotates (as with most playing card games the first player to act is to the left of the person who dealt).

As players can sit out after any round, my plan was to use a list to store the current active players (controlled by a check box for each player).

I want to use this list to determine which players need to make a move and in what order.

I keep track of which player is the dealer as seperate variable, but I am unsure on how I would correctly sort the list, or correctly sort the contents of the list based on who is currently the dealer.

An example game scenario is below.

List of active players {1,2,3,5,8,9,10}

In round one Player 1 would be the dealer, so the order of play would be 2 > 3 > 5 > 8 > 9 > 10 > 1.

However assuming no players leave the game, the order for round 3 would be 5 > 8 > 9 > 10 > 1 > 2 > 3.

Any advice on to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

My initial thoughts were that at the end of each round, I could re-order the list but I am not sure if this is the right route or not.

Answer (score 0):

To rotate the entities in a list you would basically remove the first and add him at the end. Here is a little program to elucidate this procedure.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int> players = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10 };

    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Round Nr: " + i);
        //rotate the List, shift dealer from first to last position
        int dealer = players.First();
        players.Remove(dealer);
        players.Add(dealer);

        Console.WriteLine("order of moving:");
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" > ", players));
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. How would I deal with adding a player back in though.

Players act in order from the left of the dealer relative to their postion.

So for example if in round 1 the players are {1,2,3,5,8,9,10}, then dealer would be 1 so first to act would be 2, followed by 3,5,8,9,10.

If a new player comes starts in position 7 for round to, then we will need to add him to the list (which we can do with ListName.Add, but this will add him to the end of the list), but we will need to add him between 5 and 7. So the new order for round 2 will need to be {3,5,7,8,9,10,1}.

Comment: @AntonZ "If a new player comes starts in position 7 " and " but we will need to add him between 5 and 7" is not really coherent. There is no 7 in the old list. How would you determine the new position? Based on the previous element? If so, then Dmitry has a good solution in his comment

Comment: Mong, there are a maximum of 10 player postions in the game. Players can come in at any seat position, 1 to 10. While the order of each round rotates around the dealer, the action always clockwise from the player next to the dealer alway the round back to the dealer. Its the same in a hand of poker. 

So if a new player comes in and starts playing from seat postion 7, he will need to act between the players in seat position 6 (if there is one and 8 (if there is one).

Comment: So if my starting list of active player seat positions is {1,2,3,5,8,9,10}, then round 1s action order would be 1,2,3,5,8,9,10 and round 2 would be 2,3,5,8,9,10,1.

However if a new player comes to sit in seat position 7 the new player list is {1,2,3,5,7,8,9,10} and so the order for round 2 now needs to be 2,3,5,7,8,9,10,1 not 2,3,5,8,9,10,1 as it was before. Hopefully I have explained it better this time :)!

Answer (score 0):

I think a good solution would be to use queue in this situation,
since instead of iterating through array to get next player you can simply use
`Queue.dequeue()` to get next player.

asuming you store your active players Array and dealer like this:

```
    int[] activePlayers = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10 };
    int dealer = 1;
```

I've made a simple method for you (well, not so simple, spaghetti code in fact but it works well).

```
        private Queue<int> getNextRoundQueue(int lastRoundDealer) {
        Queue<int> roundQueue = new Queue<int>();
        int indexOfDealer = -1;
        //if last round dealer is still active player
        if(activePlayers.Contains(lastRoundDealer)) {
            indexOfDealer = Array.IndexOf(activePlayers, lastRoundDealer);
        }
        //if last round dealer left get next player as a dealer
        //side note: there's gotta be a better way of doing that, but nothing came me to mind right now
        else {
            indexOfDealer = -1;
            for(int i = 0; i < activePlayers.Length; i++) {
                if(activePlayers[i] > lastRoundDealer) {
                    indexOfDealer = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(indexOfDealer == -1) indexOfDealer = 0;
        }
        //create the queue
        //add dealer as first item into the queue
        roundQueue.Enqueue(activePlayers[indexOfDealer < activePlayers.Length ? indexOfDealer : indexOfDealer - activePlayers.Length]);
        for(int i = 0; i < activePlayers.Length - 1; i++) {
            //add next player to the queue
            roundQueue.Enqueue(activePlayers[indexOfDealer + i + 1 < activePlayers.Length ? indexOfDealer + i +  1: (indexOfDealer + i + 1) - activePlayers.Length]);
        }
        return roundQueue;
    }
```

It will prepare queue for next round for you, to use it you simply do:

```
        //you get the queue using my method, you pass last round dealer as argument
        Queue<int> roundQ = getNextRoundQueue(dealer);
        //first element of the queue is the dealer of next round
        dealer = roundQ.Dequeue();
        //while there are still players in the queue
        while(roundQ.Count > 0) {
            //get current player
            int currentPlayer = roundQ.Dequeue();
            // do something with him
        }
```